# Writing an enemy class in c#: Where does one begin?

Tags: c#, class

I'm new here and have a problem. I am having to pick up `C#`, but I have no experience in it. I'll mainly end up (probably) doing tooling type stuff, but I haven't programmed in awhile and I don't know a huge bunch about it.

I have to write a class that depicts an enemy spaceship, but I am not quite sure how! I seem to have forgotten everything I learned in `Java` and `VB` about writing classes. Where might I find good resources for re-learning to write classes, learning to write a class in `C#`, and learning to write classes for video games?

Specifically, I have to show how it interacts with other enemies, weapons, how big it is, how it looks, etc.

I'm not asking for code, just for resources on learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should ask on the gamedev stackexchange platform in order to get more pertinent responses : [Gamedev Stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Also, MSDN is a good solution : [Learn Visual C# on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh341490.aspx). They describes the basics a lot, concepts, classes, structs, interfaces, with a lot of tutorials and resources (like [Creating a Maze](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/dd492162) for example).

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but:

http://www.3dbuzz.com

They have incredible tutorials on c# and C and for the most part - programming logic is programming logic, once you have a way of thinking its a lot easier irrelevant of what the language is.  They also have XNA stuff to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

You should stick to the MSDN [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). It's a good source of information for everything you need to know about `C#`.

Once you get a good hold on `C#` you should look into XNA Platform. 
It's a free Game Development Engine by microsoft for `C#`.

You can make games for Windows, Xbox360 and Windows Phone.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714

[This](http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials.shtml) is the best tutorial I know to learn how to use XNA.

Comment: I'll need this soon, I'm sure. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. You'll see it gets the job done ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you're starting from the ground up I would suggest download Microsoft's Visual Web Developer. It's a free IDE that will be very helpful for you when programming.

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express

Once you have that installed, you can follow csharp.net's introductory tutorials:
http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/introduction/

Comment: Your second link will prove most useful! Thanks!

Comment: Then how about giving me that bump up? ;)

Comment: sorry, my rep dropped back down =/

Comment: Well maybe one day then!